# Add description to json schema subtypes

Tags: java, jackson, jsonschema

I am generating json schema from my java classes with jackson, and I add the description field to all my properties like this :

```java
@NotNull
@JsonProperty (required = true)
@JsonPropertyDescription ("My description to add in schema")
private double value;
```

This work fine, and the field description is set into the json schema.

Now I have json subtypes described as below :

```java
@JsonTypeInfo (use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes ({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type (value = TriangularWaveformConfigurationEntity.class, name = "TRIANGULAR"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type (value = SquareWaveformConfigurationEntity.class, name = "SQUARE")
})
public abstract class WaveformConfigurationEntity implements ConfigurationEntity
```

And the result :

```
"waveformConfiguration" : 
{
"oneOf" : [ {
            "$ref" : "#/definitions/TriangularWaveformConfigurationEntity"
          }, {
            "$ref" : "#/definitions/SquareWaveformConfigurationEntity"
          }
          "description" : "Configuration of the waveform used to generate values"
        }
```

With the ref :

```
"TriangularWaveformConfigurationEntity" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "additionalProperties" : false,
      "properties" : {
        "type" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "enum" : [ "TRIANGULAR" ],
          "default" : "TRIANGULAR"
        },
```

My problem is that the enum value has no description, and I need this field like this :

```
"TriangularWaveformConfigurationEntity" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "additionalProperties" : false,
      "properties" : {
        "type" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "enum" : [ "TRIANGULAR" ],
          "default" : "TRIANGULAR",
          "description" : "my description"
        },
```

Note the schema are generated with the code :

```
ObjectMapper MAPPER = ConfigurationObjectMapper.createObjectMapper();
JsonSchemaGenerator jsonSchemaGenerator = new JsonSchemaGenerator(MAPPER);
JsonNode jsonSchema = jsonSchemaGenerator.generateJsonSchema(InputGeneratorConfiguration.class);

System.out.println(MAPPER.writeValueAsString(jsonSchema));
```

And the mapper

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.setVisibility(objectMapper.getSerializationConfig()
                                       .getDefaultVisibilityChecker()
                                       .withCreatorVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                                       .withGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                                       .withIsGetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                                       .withSetterVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE)
                                       .withFieldVisibility(JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY));

objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
return objectMapper;
```

Comment: I had hoped that `JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY` would allow you to use an actual Java field which can be decorated with `@JsonPropertyDescription`. However the desc is still missing which would be a bug needing to be raised on https://github.com/mbknor/mbknor-jackson-jsonSchema/issues

Comment: Thanks I have created one new issue : https://github.com/mbknor/mbknor-jackson-jsonSchema/issues/105